# Java - Read words from File and remove double quotation

Tags: java, javafx, split, java.util.scanner

I have a text file witch contains a lot of lines, where i need to find a specific "word" from the line, remove the double quotation and print it into a text Field.

```
    @FXML
private void findCFG(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.setTitle("Open cfg file");
    File cfgName = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    cfgPathLabel.setText(cfgName.getPath());



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(cfgName);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        if (word.startsWith("volume ")) {
            String[] splitter = word.split("volume ");
            for (String s : splitter) {
                volField.appendText(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My result

```
"0.1"
```

The result i want is

```
0.1
```

Comment: I've not worked with Java for some time but does `s.replaceAll("\"", "")` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all double quotes then you can use this code:

```
string=string.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

You are replacing all double quotes with nothing. Use the variable string as your String with double quotes.

Comment: `replaceAll` is for regexes. In general if no regex is required, [the `replace` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) should be prefered. In this case the result will be the same though...

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove the first and last `char` from a string, try this code:

```
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
```

Where `str` is the word with quotations. `"0.1"`